# Grep search- Find duplicated data after specific word

Tags: linux, unix, replace, grep, diff

I need to compare two txt files (json). I think grep & diff are what I need? but I'm very new to linux/programming.

This is the search I need done:

Look for: "prodId" in both documents.

Search 7 characters after "prodId" in both documents. If matches are found, change the link after word "link".

How can this be achieved in a Linux? Open to other solutions too.

Example:

**File 1**

```
{
"name":"StackOver"
"objectId": "52cZWVYWun",
"price": "62.00",
"prodId": "511040",
"link": "www.link.com/1",

},
{
"name":"Stackunder"
"objectId": "28iuo899sum",
"price": "10.00",
"prodId": "524240",
"link": "www.link.com/2",
}
```

---

**File 2**

```
{
"name":"Name1"
"objectId": "126WVYWwzzn",
"price": "2.00",
"prodId": "546040",
"link": "www.link.com/1_abcd",
},
{
"name":"Name2"
"objectId": "2wrw23um",
"price": "115.00",
"prodId": "524240",
"link": "www.link.com/2_abcd",
}
```

---

**Desired result**

Where duplicate found after "prodID", change "link":"xx" to link that exists in **File 1**

**File 1**

```
{
"name":"Stackunder"
"objectId": "28iuo899sum",
"price": "10.00",
"prodId": "524240",
"link": "www.link.com/2_abcd", //REPLACES this line data only IF a duplicate existed in File 2//
}
```

---

Does that make any more sense? Hope someone can advise.

Thanks

Comment: did you try anything??? look into grep, sed, uniq

Comment: Please provide some sample text from both the documents and sample result.

Comment: Thanks- I have updated the example. I tried using grep/diff- but I'm very new to linux so I couldn't quite get my head around how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose another approach since it is json, just read the files with your favourite script language which can read/parse json.

Something like:

1. Parse File1 into array of json objects
2. Parse File2 the same way in another array
3. Then you could have two loops eg:

PseudoCode:

```
foreach obj in File1:
   foreach obj2 in File2:
      if obj.prodId == obj2.prodId:
          obj.link = obj2.link
          remove obj2 from File2
```

If you have multiple duplicates the last one found will then be assigned to obj.

The outer loop will run for every object in File1 so every object in File2 will be tested against the first element in File1 and so on. You can then remove the duplicate from your array File2 so in the next loop you will have one less element to check.

You can of course still use grep and diff and other tools like sed/awk but i think using python, perl or php might be better/simpler for this kind of job.

There are of course much more elegant ways to solve this, this is how i would approach it.